# openXLive menu handlers

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, menu

Im using OpenXLive for my app on wp7. The leaderboards are fully implemented and working but i am having trouble setting up or finding documentation on handlers for the default menus like the new game button. Is there code in c# to handle these?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Silverlight version, you can get the 'NEW GAME' handler in `OnNavigatedTo` method.
If you use XNA version, please use the `NewGameEvent` of `XLiveFormManager`. Like the below code:

```
GameSession session = XLiveGameManager.CreateSession("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
manager = new XLiveFormManager(this, session);
session.CreateSessionCompleted += new AsyncEventHandler(session_CreateSessionCompleted);
session.Open();

manager.GameStateChanged += new XLiveFormManager.XLiveGameStateEventHandler(manager_GameStateChanged);
manager.NewGameEvent += new EventHandler(manager_NewGameEvent);
manager.ContinueGameEvent += new EventHandler(manager_ContinueGameEvent);
manager.LeaveGameEvent += new EventHandler(manager_LeaveGameEvent);
```

But we suggest use own startup menu replace the default startup UI.